# Can't disable gpg cache

Tags: gnupg

I want to encrypt files and *NEVER* cache passwords. In my opinion, this is a terrible security issue and the reason gnu chose to make this feature the default is beyond me.

Someone told me to try `gpg -c --no-symkey-cache`
I tried but got this error `gpg: invalid option "--no-symkey-cache"`
What do I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

What's your `gpg --version`?

`--no-symkey-cache` was added in [gpg 2.2.7](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2018q2/000424.html).

[Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/gpg) only has gpg 2.2.4. You'll need [Ubuntu 18.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/gpg) or later. Or upgrade gpg manually.

Comment: Where  does gpg cache passphrases that the OP is referring to? I don't see any such file

Comment: I think it's cached by `gpg-agent` in memory, not a file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` for conflicting options, or temporarily move a gpg.conf file.

```
gpg -c --no-symkey-cache test.txt
```

works fine for me.